# How to ssh vps and play the video?

Tags: ssh, ffmpeg

I build apache2 on vps,start it,and upload test.mp4 into /var/www/html.

```
ffplay  http://vps_ip/test.mp4
```

I can watch test.mp4 ,maybe there is a other way to play it.

```
1.ssh root@vps_ip
2.mv /var/www/html/test.mp4  /tmp/test.mp4
3.ffplay /tmp/test.mp4

Could not initialize SDL - No available video device
(Did you set the DISPLAY variable?)
```

libsdl2-dev and sdl are all installed on my vps.
How to ffplay it after sshing login it?

Answer (score 0):

To show a graphical application over SSH, you use X forwarding. However, X forwarding a video player will result in a stream of the full unencrypted video coming down the pipe, which probably won't work well (assuming that it even plays at all).

Download the video and play it on your local machine instead.